# Email notifications

Tags: trigger

we are facing some task completed mails...After receiving completion mail we are unable to insert RelatedTo field.while we are trying to insert RelatedTo field it has showing in the template Related to = null.Can any one please help us on this issue.

***template+= 'Related To-{4}: '+tsk.What+' \n';***

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My Out put is Like this : Your Task has been Completed. Here are the details - 

Subject-{1}: To Do_test task4 
Status-{2}: Completed 
Priority-{3}: Low 
What-{4}: null

Comment: Your *expected* output... Linked name? Id? Something else? `What` isn't a field, it's just a name pointing reference. It gives you back the whole object.

Comment: Here What -> Field Name ,Related To -> Field Label name  My Expected out put is :  Related To = Opportunity 25:  for that we are using below code:template+= 'Subject-{1}: '+tsk.Subject+' \n';
            template+= 'Status-{2}: '+tsk.Status +' \n';
            template+= 'Priority-{3}: '+tsk.Priority +' \n';
           template+= 'Related To-{4}: '+tsk.What+' \n';

Comment: That's not output, it's input. What are you expecting to see after `Related To:-{4}:`?

Comment: Am expecting see after Related To : Opportunity  or case some thing like that .Thats depends on selection relatedTo.But hear am getting Related To = Null

Comment: Try using `What.Type` instead of `What`. That sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Larson,  Still am facing same issue. in my org  "Related To" is the field Label and "what" is the Field name. So how we can insert that field name?